# How can I deploy a Laravel 4 application for production?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When we are developping a Laravel app, we can use

```
php artisan serve
```

to serve Laravel. However, I saw in other StackOverflow posts that we should **NEVER** use this command for production

So, how can we serve Laravel? Is there a command for it? I couldn't find a straightforward tutorial that teaches how to deploy Laravel for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point the server on the config file to the public folder for example in apache:

Change DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" to DocumentRoot "C:/laravel/appname/public/"

On the production Server

Comment: I'm not using Xampp, I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) and I have installed everything separately, so it would be in /var/www?

Comment: Actually, your answer is the correct one. I didn't understand it until I read this article: http://wiki.laravel.io/A_Beginner's_Guide_to_Laravel_4#Set_up_a_web_server

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan serve` uses [PHP's build in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) which is designed purely for development purposes. In order for this to work for everyone else, you're going to need a more powerful server.

You're main two options will be [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) and [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main). I don't want to recommend any guides because I haven't read any (I learned on the job so I might be doing things wrong myself). However, the internet is full of guides, and articles describing the differences between the two.

Comment: I see... I have apache already, but the question is: how to deploy a Laravel application with Apache... do I need to move the laravel project folder to /var/www?

Comment: You can, but it might be better to use virtual hosts if you want to have more than one site on the same server. On Ubuntu, you can create a virtual  host in `/etc/apache/sites-available` and activate it with `sudo a2ensite <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, edits to Filipe Ferreira's answer have been rejected. Here is some important information on how to deploy Laravel4 to apache

You can point the server on the config file to the public folder for example in apache:

Change DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" to DocumentRoot "C:/laravel/appname/public/"

On the production Server

Or, in Linux, you can follow the steps described [HERE](http://wiki.laravel.io/A_Beginner's_Guide_to_Laravel_4#Set_up_a_web_server)

Also, when deploying, DO remember to have mod_rewrite enabled

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And to configure your .htaccess file, as shows [HERE](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working)